# problem with wlan0 on a rpi4 with raspbian + kodi

Tags: pi-4, wireless, raspberry-pi-os-buster

not sure if this is where i should be posting this, I've been using rpi 4 for a year now, and lately, it looks like wifi is disconnecting randomly (like a month ago i moved and now the raspberry is very close to the router, but no ethernet cable).

This is happening every 5/6 hours, then it works normally again.

I opened a screen session with iwevent and see this:

```
15:02:55.350035 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0

15:09:54.649670 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D33304330010882848B962430486C32040C121860210203142402010D30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC0200004605324

15:09:54.649798 wlan0 Association Response IEs:010882848B962430486C32040C121860460502000000002D1AAC091FFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003D16010804000000000000000

15:09:54.649891 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:BC:30:D9:77:30:C2

15:16:55.555100 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D3330433001088C1218243048606C210203E0240624043404640B30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC02000046053248010

15:16:55.555192 wlan0 Association Response IEs:01088C1218243048606C2D1A6F0017FF000000000000000000000001000000000018E6E719003D1664050500000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1

15:16:55.555248 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0

15:17:03.937035 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated

15:17:06.537909 wlan0 Scan request completed

15:17:09.175157 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D3330433001088C1218243048606C210203E0240624043404640B30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC02000046053248010

15:17:09.175337 wlan0 Association Response IEs:01088C1218243048606C2D1A6F0017FF000000000000000000000001000000000018E6E719003D1664050500000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1

15:17:09.175432 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0

15:22:11.627386 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D33304330010882848B962430486C32040C121860210203142402010D30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC0200004605324

15:22:11.627477 wlan0 Association Response IEs:010882848B962430486C32040C121860460502000000002D1AAC091FFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003D16010804000000000000000

15:22:11.627537 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:BC:30:D9:77:30:C2

15:28:54.721469 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D3330433001088C1218243048606C210203E0240624043404640B30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC02000046053248010

15:28:54.721547 wlan0 Association Response IEs:01088C1218243048606C2D1A6F0017FF000000000000000000000001000000000018E6E719003D1664050400000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1

15:28:54.721602 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0

15:35:55.443244 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D33304330010882848B962430486C32040C121860210203142402010D30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC0200004605324

15:35:55.443379 wlan0 Association Response IEs:010882848B962430486C32040C121860460502000000002D1AAC091FFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003D16010804000000000000000

15:35:55.443513 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:BC:30:D9:77:30:C2

15:41:54.099590 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D3330433001088C1218243048606C210203E0240624043404640B30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC02000046053248010

15:41:54.099670 wlan0 Association Response IEs:01088C1218243048606C2D1A6F0017FF000000000000000000000001000000000018E6E719003D1664050500000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1

15:41:54.099726 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0

15:42:02.383611 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated

15:42:04.982228 wlan0 Scan request completed

15:42:07.625881 wlan0 Association Response IEs:01088C1218243048606C2D1A6F0017FF000000000000000000000001000000000018E6E719003D1664050500000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1

15:42:07.626002 wlan0 Association Request IEs:000C4D6946696272612D3330433001088C1218243048606C210203E0240624043404640B30140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC02000046053248010

15:42:07.626094 wlan0 New Access Point/Cell address:5A:30:D9:77:30:C0
```

what could be the reason for this intermittent connection or how can i find the cause for this? Maybe router is too close to the raspberry now? How can this be checked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really mean from the title to use a virtual lan **vlan0**? What operating system, what version do you use? Do you have done an update (sudo apt update) the last time?

Comment: hi, sorry there was a typo there, i'm running on raspbian buster and i run the sudo apt update last week

Answer (score 2):

With another setup I have found that the image versions of the **Raspberry Pi OS** come with an unstable firmware for the built-in WiFi device. I don't know if it is the same issue than with your problem but it's worth a try to downgrade to a more stable firmware. For further information look at my bug report at [WiFi firmware brcmfmac crashes when using virtual AP interface](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1463). The last stable is [firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/) comming with image **Raspbian Buster Lite 2020-02-13**.

So we can downgrade the WiFi firmware to this stable version as long as the bug isn't fixed. Before going on it is always a good idea to take a backup of your SD Card. Then follow this to do a downgrade:

```
rpi ~$ wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --purge firmware-brcm80211
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --install firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb
rpi ~$ sudo apt-mark hold firmware-brcm80211
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Comment: If you follow the GitHub repo for the RPi firmware, the [number of open issues](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues) suggests there are some real problems. As of this writing, there are ***277 open issues*** ... firmware, Raspberry Pi. This is troubling given the firmware is the foundation for most everything else.

Comment: @Seamus I suppose there are many things already fixed with other updates by side effects but the fixes are not dedicated to the open issues. No one have checked them again with recent firmware.

Comment: I admire your optimism. :)