# Linux wifi hotspot

Tags: wifi

I start with the Dependencies from this tutorial: https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot I get the ui by typing wihotspot into the terminal. At wifi Interface I can just select wlan1, and at internet Interface I can choose between those:

[image]

I select wlan1 left and wlan1 right. But if I click on **Create hotspot** I get this error message:

> pkexec --user root create_ap wlan1 wlan0 'MyAccessPoint' ''
> --mkconfig /etc/create_ap.conf --freq-band 2.4  Config options written to '/etc/create_ap.conf' WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
> it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
> interfaces for your adapter.
> For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203 ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time Command not found or exited with error status

**Edit:**
If I wanna start the ap with the terminal using this command:
`sudo create_ap wlan0 rename4 mywifi mypassword1233645`
I get:

> WARN: Your adapter does not fully support AP virtual interface, enabling --no-virt Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.QawjYzJX PID: 20869 Sharing Internet using method: nat  dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use  Doing cleanup.. done

And if I turn it around like this: `sudo create_ap rename4 wlan0 mywifi mypassword1233645`
I get:

> WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and       it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual       interfaces for your adapter.       For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203 ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time

The wifi dongle where I want to create the ap is TL-WN725N.

Comment: I'm sorry that no one bothered to re-open this earlier.  Anyway, WRT *"I select wlan1 left and wlan1 right"*, I would guess the cause of your problem is that the `wlan1` adapter cannot be used as an AP and an uplink at the same time.  Since this is referred to in relation to the `brcmfmac` driver, `wlan1` is probably the built-in wifi adapter (have you tried `wlan0`? Which adapter gets which name is arbitrary at boot unless you configure otherwise).  Have a look at  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118424/5538

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for opening. On the left, I can just select wlan1, and wlan0 is the built-in chip, and wlan1 the wifi dongle

Comment: If `wlan0` is the built-in it is odd that you can't select it.  When providing that kind of information it is a good idea to indicate why you believe something, not just that you believe it -- eg., "wlan0 is the built-in chip", how do you know that?  After all, you are the one asking for help/information, which implies you are not the expert ;)

Comment: I know that wlan0 is the built-in chip, because I have a code, that set the built-in chip to ``wlan0``

Comment: That's no different than saying, "I know the sky is green because I wrote it down".  The point is **you need to clearly demonstrate (prove) that something you claim is true is true**.  This is a pretty simple criteria because all you need to do is think, "if someone else told me this, would I think the reason they gave actually proves what they are saying?".  The problem is not about arguing -- I am not trying to insist you are wrong -- the problem is that if you cannot demonstrate what you are saying is accurate then people will loose interest in helping you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear and unequivocal:

> Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time

This means your adapter can either be uplinked (ie., connected to an exterior network such as your WLAN) *or* act as an access point, ie., create a network of its own to which other systems may attach.

To create an access point and be connected to the internet you will need to another adapter and bridge the two (presumably that GUI tool will do that).

However, I believe the built-in wifi should be able to connect and act as an AP without another adapter, although you are saying it is not even available in part of the GUI.  This may be because of [some firmware issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118424/5538) or because of a flaw in the GUI. You would have to try and configure this manually to tell.

Comment: Now I try to create a hotspot with the command line version. I typed: `sudo create_ap wlan0 rename4 mywifi mypassword1233645` and I get: `WARN: Your adapter does not fully support AP virtual interface, enabling --no-virt
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.QawjYzJX
PID: 20869
Sharing Internet using method: nat

dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use

Doing cleanup.. done`
rename4 is wlan1!

Comment: If I turn it around like this: `sudo create_ap rename4 wlan0 mywifi mypassword1233645` 

I get: `WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time
`
I hope this helps you

Comment: It's not me that needs help -- again good luck with your problem, and remember: We are **not** a discussion site.  If you have a new question, ask a new question the same way you asked this one.